# Can anyone help me to handle 'system.nullreferenceexception' on following code?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public FeeDetails GetFeeDetails(string admissionno)
{
   var feedetails = from f in db.FeeDetails select f;

    FeeDetails feedetail = feedetails.Where(f => f.AdmissionNo == admissionno).FirstOrDefault();
    FeeDetails feedetailfinal = new FeeDetails();

    feedetailfinal.Fee1 = feedetail.Fee1.ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee1.ToString()) : 0;
    feedetailfinal.Fee2 = feedetail.Fee2.ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee2.ToString()) : 0;
    feedetailfinal.Fee3 = feedetail.Fee3.ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee3.ToString()) : 0;
    feedetailfinal.Fee4 = feedetail.Fee4.ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee4.ToString()) : 0;
    feedetailfinal.Fee5 = feedetail.Fee5.ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee5.ToString()) : 0;


    return feedetailfinal;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `feedetail` is not `null` ?

Comment: Put a check `if(feedetail!=null)` then access values from it.

Comment: Which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive each your line should look like this:

```
if(feedetail != null)
{
    feedetailfinal.Fee1 = feedetail.Fee1 != null 
                      ? Convert.ToInt32(feedetail.Fee1) 
                      : 0;
    //other lines
}
```

Comment: it is returning 0 for all records so i and using:

if(feedetail != null)
            {
                feedetailfinal.Fee1 = feedetail.Fee1;
                feedetailfinal.Fee2 = feedetail.Fee2;
                feedetailfinal.Fee3 = feedetail.Fee3;
                feedetailfinal.Fee4 = feedetail.Fee4;                
            }           

            return feedetailfinal;